# backslash char alternatives on windows

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, terminal

On linux I can rappresent the / char in a different way:

***${HOME:0:1}***

So, for example, `cat ${HOME:0:1}etc${HOME:0:1}passwd` would be treated like `cat /etc/passwd`

Is there any way I can do the same thing on windows via powershell and cmd.exe for the backslash?

Comment: are you talking about the just the path?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala yes! in a native way, without variables or scripts

Comment: No, PowerShell variable expressions doesn't support this type of string slicing - for the simple reason that a variable in PowerShell _might very well not be a string_ :)

Comment: why on earth would you want that? And in PowerShell there are so many ways to get substrings, for example `cat ($HOME[0] + "etc" + $HOME[0] + "passwd")` or `cat ("{0}etc{0}passwd" -f $HOME[0])`. For longer substrings just use `$HOME.Substring(1, 3)`

Comment: @phuclv ahaha just curiosity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PowerShell has *no* equivalent to the [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) available in POSIX-compatible shells** such as Bash, of which your substring extraction (`${HOME:0:1}` to get the substring of length `1` at character position `0`, i.e the first char. of the value of variable `$HOME`) is an example (link is to the Bash manual).

However, PowerShell makes it easy:

- to embed the results of arbitrary expressions and even whole statements inside [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules#double-quoted-strings), using `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--).
- to pass the results of any expression or command (pipeline) as an argument to a command, by enclosing it in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--).

The following command variations are equivalent, and dynamically use the platform-appropriate path (directory) separator, i.e. `/` on Unix-like platforms, and `\` on Windows:

```
# -> '/etc/passwd' on Unix
# -> '\etc\passwd' on Windows
Write-Output "$([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)etc$([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)passwd"

# Ditto.
Write-Output ('{0}etc{0}passwd' -f [System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)
```

See also:

- [`[System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
- `-f`, the string [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f)

Comment: ok done, nvm ahah

Comment: You're welcome, @jagghy. Sounds like you figured out the answer to the follow-up question yourself, but just to spell it out: you need `"..."` strings for string interpolation (situationally, quoting is optional); by contrast `'...'` strings are _verbatim_ strings.